# Modal não está dando scroll

Tags: html, css, modal

### CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }
    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
    .close:hover {
        background: #00d9ff;
    }
```

Tentei colocar esse código embaixo no .modalDialog > div porém ele fica meio desformatado. Teria alguma maneira de fazer o scroll e não mostrar a barra de rolagem?

> ```
> max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
> overflow-y: auto;
> ```

Veja o exemplo no jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/4067/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.modalDialog {
/*Insira o código debaixo de tudo*/
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Vê se da ai!

Comment: Nossa algo tão simples, obrigado cara. já te dou upvote tem que esperar uns 10 minutos.

Comment: Mas a minha ideia seria fazer o scroll no próprio modal entendeu?

Comment: Mas solucionou o problema ? @Marcel

Comment: Sim, mas eu gostaria de fazer de outro jeito onde o scroll ocorra no próprio modal. Sem dar scroll na página inteira entendeu?

Comment: @MarceloT.Cortes coloca um height no .modalDialog > div não uso o JsFiddle mas tenta ai para ver se alterou alguma coisa http://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/4071/

Comment: Blz valeu cara já ajudou bastante o resto eu me viro aqui.

Answer (score -2):

> Sim, mas eu gostaria de fazer de outro jeito onde o scroll ocorra no próprio modal. Sem dar scroll na página inteira entendeu?

*Encontrei a seguinte solução que resolve esse problema:*

HTML: (Ignora o Blade)

```
<div id="fade" class="hide"></div>
    <div id="modal" class="hide">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Selecione o Item que deseja Encaminhar para a Saida</h2>
        <button id="close-modal" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
                <th scope="col">Marca</th>
                <th scope="col">Ações</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($materials as $material)
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">{{ $material->nome }}</a></td>
                      <td>{{ $material->quantidade }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $material->marca }}</td>
                      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Encaminhar</a></td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#fade {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
  #modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 90%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1.2rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  
  #fade,
  #modal {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  
  .modal-body p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  
  #modal.hide,
  #fade.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #modal.hide {
    top: 0;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
const openModalButton = document.querySelector("#open-modal");
const closeModalButton = document.querySelector("#close-modal");
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const fade = document.querySelector("#fade");

const toggleModal = () => {
  modal.classList.toggle("hide");
  fade.classList.toggle("hide");
};

[openModalButton, closeModalButton, fade].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => toggleModal());
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).